# combining temp tables in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 temp tables in my procedure .
I want to combine both of them .
Could any one please help how to do this

Temp 1 :

[image]

Temp 2 :

[image]

Output :

[image]

I tried with full join by joining Team column, but I am getting result like below.

[image]

Comment: What about INNER JOIN with the TEAM ? Can you please share your query ?

Comment: Please show your code.  And why isn't this just an `inner join`?

Comment: Hey @SandraGuilepZouaouiZandeh and gordon some times the tempt 1 table has data where temp 2 doent have .and its vice versa too. So I took full join

Comment: Consumable sample data is far better than images. Please don't ask us to transcribe your data. Also, why doesn't your attempt(s) work? What *were* you attempts?

Comment: Downvoted for [multi-posting](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fa226240-4fb3-4a43-8997-b228f64e861d/combining-temp-tables-in-stored-procedure?forum=databasedesign).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/49152a/2)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Temp1([Date] date, Team char(2),Calls int)
CREATE TABLE Temp2([Date] date, Team char(2),Messages int)
INSERT INTO Temp1([Date],Team,Calls)VALUES
('5/12/2020','T1',12),('5/12/2020','T2',29)
                 ,('5/12/2020','T3',46)
INSERT INTO Temp2([Date],Team,Messages)VALUES
('5/12/2020','T1',45),('5/12/2020','T2',27),
('5/12/2020','T3',50)
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT A.[Date],A.Team,A.Calls,B.Messages FROM Temp1 AS A
INNER JOIN Temp2 AS B ON A.Team=B.Team
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/49152a/2/0)**:

```
|       Date | Team | Calls | Messages |
|------------|------|-------|----------|
| 2020-05-12 |   T1 |    12 |       45 |
| 2020-05-12 |   T2 |    29 |       27 |
| 2020-05-12 |   T3 |    46 |       50 |
```

Comment: Hi Sandra ,

Thank you.

I tried this, But what some times there would be no data in my second temp tables.

In that case I am not getting even first temp table data itself as I am using inner joins



Its vice vesra too for the first table

Comment: @vissubabu how are you populating these two tables?

Answer (score 1):

You can use also LEFT JOIN

```
Select A.date as 'Date', A.team as Team, A.calls as 'Calls', B.messages as 'Messages'
from Temp1 as A
left join Temp2 as B on
(
  A.date = B.date
and A.team = B.team
)
```